# assign permissions to a created role?

Tags: 7, users

i want to assign permissions to a role in my `hook_install()` , but the permissions that i'm adding are part of my modules `hook_permission`()
 don't exist yet?
so how to grant permissions role created in `hook_install` after `hook_permission` ?

NB :

- i have D7.23
       -
- my module create the role and his permissions .

  Thanks.

Comment: problem resolved by set permissions in hook_install() user_role_grant_permissions($pub_role_rid,array_keys(module_invoke('my_module', 'permission'))); after creation of my custom role.

Comment: you can add that as an answer also specify the links to the resources from where you find out. However I wonder whether this is a proper way to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972588/create-a-permission-and-set-a-role-to-it-on-module-install

Comment: i'm used array_keys(module_invoke('my_module', 'permission') to get only the permissions of ma custom module thanks Mathankumar .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution found in http://www.dibe.gr/blog/drupal-7-create-users-and-roles-programmatically in the author comment , so i'm set only the permissions array of my custom module in `hook_install()` `user_role_grant_permissions($role_rid,array_keys(module_invoke('my_module', 'permission')));`